# Warum „am Bahnhof ankommen“ anstatt „an den Bahnhof“?

Tags: verb, dative, accusative

*Ankommen* ist ein Bewegungsverb. Dementsprechend sollte es allem Anschein nach den Akkusativ verlangen, denn *an* geht beides mit Akkusativ und Dativ. Wieso dann:

> am Bahnhof ankommen

und nicht Folgendes:

> an den Bahnhof ankommen

Wie kann man sich den Dativ da erklären?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, was "Bewegungsverb" bedeuten soll, aber die Anwendung auf *ankommen* dürfte zweifelhaft sein. *Ankommen* beschreibt nicht wirklich eine Bewegung, sondern einen kurzfristig existierenden Zustand beim Übergang von Bewegung zum Stillstand. Der Fokus liegt dabei auf dem Stillstand, denn mit der Ankunft ist die Reise beendet und die Reisenden sind am Ankunftsort mit anderen Dingen beschäftigt. Deshalb die Präposition *an* mit Dativ und nicht *zu* (ebenfalls mit Dativ) oder *an* mit Akkusativ.

Das Englische z.B. sieht das auch nicht anders. Auch auf Englisch heißt es "arrive at the station" ("am Bahnhof ankommen"), nicht "arrive to the station" ("zum Bahnhof ankommen").

Falls man den Fokus doch lieber auf die Bewegung legen will, benutzt man ein anderes Verb, z.B. *kommen* oder im Englischen *come*.

PS:

Es ist auch relevant, dass *ankommen* ein separables Verb ist, das mit der Präposition *an* beginnt. Das Verb *kommen* kann mit verschiedenen Präpositionen flexibel angepasst werden, um Ursprung und/oder Ziel der Bewegung und/oder Details der Bewegung selbst zu beschreiben:

- *aus* Wien kommen / *von* Wien kommen / *vom* Bahnhof kommen
- *nach* Berlin kommen / *zum* Bahnhof kommen / *an* den Bahnhof kommen.
- *mit* dem Zug kommen / *mit* der Familie kommen / *auf* der Autobahn kommen

Bei manchen dieser Verwendungen hat wohl das Bedürfnis, das Objekt der Präposition wegzulassen zur Entstehung eines separablen Verbs geführt. Unter den obigen Beispielen gilt das für *ankommen* von "*an* den Bahnhof kommen" und *mitkommen* von "*mit* der Familie kommen" (aber nicht "*mit* dem Zug kommen"). Diese Art von separablem Verb wird gelegentlich zusammen mit einer anderen Präposition verwendet, um zusätzlich einen weiterer Aspekt anzugeben. Beispiel: "zum Bahnhof mitkommen". Vielleicht noch häufiger aber wird das separable Verb wie das Grundverb benutzt und die Präposition dadurch verdoppelt: "am Bahnhof ankommen", "mit der Familie mitkommen". Das verdeutlicht dann die Präposition, ohne sie unbedingt zu betonen. Oft lässt sich auch beides kombinieren: "mit dem Gast zum Bahnhof mitkommen".

Comment: Ich denke, du meinst entweder "zu (mit Dativ)" oder "an (mit Akkusativ)".

Comment: Ach so. Dann *wo kommst du an?* und nicht *wohin kommst du an?* wäre die Frage.

Comment: Und deshalb auch "ich komme zu Hause an".

Comment: Ich war etwas durcheinander gekommen. Ich hoffe, es ist jetzt richtiger und klarer.

Comment: @c.p.: Richtig, die passende Frage ist "Wo kommst du an?".

Answer (score 7):

Du gehst von einer falschen Prämisse aus. »Ankommen« ist kein Verb der Bewegung, sondern ein situatives Verb, wobei ich nicht weiß, ob die Bezeichnung »situatives Verb« korrekt ist. Daher will ich etwas ausführlicher erklären, was gemeint ist:

### Verben mit einer Direktiv-Ergänzung

Verben der Bewegung haben (falls sie eine Ergänzung haben) eine Ergänzung, nach der man mit »wohin« fragen kann:

> gehen: Wohin gehst du?
>   fahren: Wohin fährst du?
>   fliegen: Wohin fliegst du?
>   schwimmen: Wohin schwimmst du?
>   usw.

Setzte man in dieses Schema »ankommen« ein, erkennt man, dass hier etwas nicht stimmt:

> ankommen: Wohin kommst du an? - Falsch!

Die Antwort auf die Frage »wohin« ist eine Direktiv-Ergänzung, also ein Ausdruck, der das Ziel einer Ortsveränderung darstellt. Diese Direktiv-Ergänzung kann wie folgt gebildet werden:

**lokale Präposition + Dativ-Objekt**

> Ich gehe *zu Hans*.
>   Ich fahre *nach Berlin*.

**Wechsel-Präposition + Akkusativ-Objekt**

> Ich fliege *in die Schweiz*.
>   Ich schwimme *an das Ufer*. (= ans Ufer)

---

### Verben, die das Verharren an einem Ort ausdrücken

Orts-Verben (ich weiß leider nicht wie man diese Gruppe von Verben tatsächlich nennt) drücken aus, dass sich jemand oder etwas an einem bestimmten Ort befindet. Nach der jeweiligen Ergänzung fragt man nicht mit »wohin«, sondern mit »wo«:

> stehen: Wo stehst du?
>   liegen: Wo liegst du?
>   sitzen: Wo sitzt du?
>   usw.

In diese Gruppe passt auch ankommen:

> ankommen: Wo kommst du an? - Richtig!

Die Antwort auf diese Wo-Fragen werden wie folgt gebildet:

**Wechsel-Präposition + Dativ-Objekt**

> Ich stehe *neben der Laterne*.
>   Ich liege *in dem Bett*. (= im Bett)
>   Ich sitze *auf einer Kiste*.

Und natürlich auch:

> Ich komme *an dem Bahnhof* an. (= am Bahnhof)